# String not callable exception raised when trying to use fields.String with enum in flask-restplus

Tags: python, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I try to use req parser with a fields.String enum to display a nice dropdown in swagger:

```
seen_search_parser = api.parser()
seen_search_parser.add_argument('page', type=int, default=1, help='Page number')
seen_search_parser.add_argument('max', type=int, default=100, help='Seen entries per page')
seen_search_parser.add_argument('local_seen', type=fields.String(enum=['true', 'false', 'all'], default='all')

@seen_api.route('/')
class SeenSearchAPI(APIResource):
    @api.response(404, 'Page does not exist')
    @api.response(200, 'Successfully retrieved seen objects', seen_search_schema)
    @api.doc(parser=seen_search_parser)
    def get(self, session):
        """ Search for seen entries """
        args = seen_search_parser.parse_args()
```

I the use the `expect` wrapper and I do see this nicely in swagger. But when I try to send the request I get a validation error. When debugging I get a `error: String object is not callable` raised from the [`reqparse.convert`](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/blob/master/flask_restplus/reqparse.py#L219) method:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "local_seen": "'String' object is not callable"
  },
  "message": "Input payload validation failed"
}
```

Why is that? I am sending a string value obviously under the parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it has to be type name without () and arguments - `type=fields.String` - but I can't work as you expect.

Comment: without the arguments i can't configure enum and that's kinda the whole point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in the git issue:

I forgot but RequestParser can also handle string enumerations

```
seen_search_parser = api.parser()
seen_search_parser.add_argument('page', type=int, default=1, help='Page number')
seen_search_parser.add_argument('max', type=int, default=100, help='Seen entries per page')
seen_search_parser.add_argument('local_seen', type=str, default='all',
                                choices=('true', 'false', 'all'),
                                help='Filter list by local status.')


class MyResource(Resource):
    @api.expect(seen_search)
    def get(self):
        args = seen_search..parse_args()
        local_seen = args['local_seen']
        if local_seen == 'true':
            # true case
        elif local_seen == 'false':
            # false case
        elif local_seen == 'all':
            # all case
```

Comment: should be `@api.expect(seen_search_parser)`

Answer (score 0):

I'll just copy-paste answer on the [github issue](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/124#issuecomment-175578758)

`RequestParser` expect types from `flask_restplus.inputs` module. (See https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/blob/master/flask_restplus/inputs.py#L372-L393 for example)

You can write your own, in you case:

```py
def local_seen(value):
    if value not in ('true', 'false', 'all'):
        raise ValueError('Unexpected value {0}'.format(value))


seen_search_parser = api.parser()
seen_search_parser.add_argument('page', type=int, default=1, help='Page number')
seen_search_parser.add_argument('max', type=int, default=100, help='Seen entries per page')
seen_search_parser.add_argument('local_seen', type=local_seen, default='all',
                                help='Filter list by local status.')


class MyResource(Resource):
    @api.expect(seen_search)
    def get(self):
        args = seen_search..parse_args()
        local_seen = args['local_seen']
        if local_seen == 'true':
            # true case
        elif local_seen == 'false':
            # false case
        elif local_seen == 'all':
            # all case
```

My advice, use boolean and assume 'all' when not specified:

```py
from flask_restplus.inputs import boolean

seen_search_parser = api.parser()
seen_search_parser.add_argument('page', type=int, default=1, help='Page number')
seen_search_parser.add_argument('max', type=int, default=100, help='Seen entries per page')
seen_search_parser.add_argument('local_seen', type=boolean, help='Filter list by local status.')

class MyResource(Resource):
    @api.expect(seen_search)
    def get(self):
        args = seen_search..parse_args()
        local_seen = args['local_seen']
        if local_seen is True:
            # true case
        elif local_seen is False:
            # false case
        elif local_seen is None:
            # all case
```

Comment: I'll post my reply from the Git issue as well: Thank you for your suggestion, custom enum is in fact what I have been successfully using until now. 
However, when using the fields.String with enum as type, swagger ui shows a drop down input as opposed to a textual one, which is a lot nicer. If a default value is set it pre selects it as well. I was wondering if and how that swagger ui element is currently available with restplus.